# How does incrementation operator work within a loop

Tags: perl

I've just started off with perl, and while trying out a few compound statements, I wrote this:

```
my $ct;
while ($ct++ < 10) {
    print $ct;
}
```

It prints out:

```
12345678910
```

I was not expecting it to print 10. How does the logic for the loop really work?

According to perdoc, a TERM operator has the highest precedence. $ct gets incremented to 10 after  iterating the loop where it is 9. When it becomes 10, while loop is supposed to exit. So why is 10 still printed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it like

```
while ($ct < 10) {
    $ct += 1;
    print $ct;
}
```

(increment after comparison)

On the other hand, `++` on the left side of the variable will increment first, and then do comparison,

```
while (++$ct < 10) {
    print $ct;
}
```

This is quite intuitive for someone with `C` background; from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> "++" and "--" work as in C. That is, if placed before a variable, they increment or decrement the variable by one before returning the value, and if placed after, increment or decrement after returning the value.

Comment: So the incrementation actually occurs after the loop is entered.. Hmm.

Comment: @Droidzone this is just illustration to better grasp the concept.

Comment: @Droidzone: No, the increment occurs as part of `$ct++` but the expression's *value* is whatever `$ct` was *before* the increment. A postfixed `++` works like `sub postfixed_inc { my $save = $_[0]; $_[0] += 1; return $save; }` Then `print "$i\n" while postfixed_inc($i) < 10` is identical to `print "$i\n" while $i++ < 10`

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that `$var++` has become more popular than `++$var` (which works the way you would expect, and returns the value *after* the increment) only because of the name `C++` for the language. It it very rare to need anything other than `++$var`, and you should change your habits as, apart from being unnecessary, `$var++` is potentially slower because the underlying code has to save the original value so that it can return it (although in most cases a compiler will optimise that away if the returned value isn't used, as in the case of a bare `$var++` as a single statement)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using the postfix operator. its first compared then incremented.

Comment: That's not really true. The comparison is done *after* the increment, but the value returned by the increment operator is the *old* value of the variable.

Comment: @Borodin you are right when looking at it from behind the scene, but from the programmer POV if the comparison is using the old value, then...